# Passing object as a variable

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I got an array (see below for one object in the array). I would like to access the object via a variable that I will pass in. Can you please explain why variable whatType does not work?

```
 const myfunction = (whatType) => {
    var mylist = {
        bio: null,
        email:  "user@domain.com",
        firstname: "Anna",
        id: 318,
        lastAvatar: null,
        lastMessage: null,
        lastname: "Nickson",
        nickname: "anny"
     };
      console.log (mylist.whatType)
    }

firstfunction () {
    const passthis = 'bio';
    myfunction (passthis);
};
```

Comment: First. There is no array, it’s an object. You need to actually assign whatstype to the object somewhere for it to be available.

Comment: `mylist` does not have a key of `whatType`. It has a key of `bio`, `email`, `firstname`, etc... But no key of `whatType`

Comment: You can have an array of objects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to replace `console.log (mylist.whatType)` by `console.log (mylist[whatType])`

Because

`mylist.bio === mylist['bio']`

And if `bio` is a String on `whatType` variable you have to use:

`mylist[whatType]` to replaced by `mylist["bio"]` (it's same that `mylist.bio`)

You function will be (with better names)

```
const getUserField = (attr) => {
    var user = {
        bio: null,
        email:  "user@domain.com",
        firstname: "Anna",
        id: 318,
        lastAvatar: null,
        lastMessage: null,
        lastname: "Nickson",
        nickname: "anny"
    }
    return user[attr]
}

firstfunction () {
    const attr = 'bio';
    console.log("User value for " + attr + ":", getUserField (attr))
}
```

Comment: `mylist` does not have a key of `whatType`. This would be `undefined`

Comment: @MaxBaldwin `whatType` is a variable with a string in it. Like `'bio'`

Comment: Right, but `mylist.whatType` and `mylist[whatType]` will both be undefined because there is no `whatType` key in `mylist`. It's not defined.

Comment: @MaxBaldwin: `mylist.whatType` and `mylist[whatType]` are in no way the same thing.  In this code the latter will resolve to `mylist['bio']` which is defined.  (albeit `null`)

Comment: Try this: `let foo = { key: "it's work"}; let attr = "key"; console.log(foo.attr, foo[attr]);`. It'll give you: `undefined, It's work`

Answer (score 0):

```
const myfunction = (whatType) => {
var mylist = {};
    mylist[whatType] = {
        bio: null,
        email:  "user@domain.com",
        firstname: "Anna",
        id: 318,
        lastAvatar: null,
        lastMessage: null,
        lastname: "Nickson",
        nickname: "anny"
     };
      console.log (mylist[whatType])
    }

firstfunction () {
    const passthis = 'bio';
    myfunction (passthis);
};
```

Answer (score -1):

if you want access  whatType from mylist you need to add it to mylist as a property.

```js
const myfunction = (whatType) => {
  var mylist = {
    bio: null,
    email: "user@domain.com",
    firstname: "Anna",
    id: 318,
    lastAvatar: null,
    lastMessage: null,
    lastname: "Nickson",
    nickname: "anny",
    whatType
  };
  console.log(mylist.whatType)
}


const passthis = 'bio';
myfunction(passthis);
```

if your goal is to query an object based on a variable property name then you can use brackets :

```js
const myfunction = (whatType) => {
  var mylist = {
    bio: null,
    email: "user@domain.com",
    firstname: "Anna",
    id: 318,
    lastAvatar: null,
    lastMessage: null,
    lastname: "Nickson",
    nickname: "anny",
    whatType
  };
  console.log(mylist[whatType])
}

const passthis = 'bio';
myfunction(passthis);
```